# Modifying a batch script to affect all user accounts

Tags: firefox, batch-file, cookies, windows-7, browser-history

I found a script for removing firefox cookies and web cache to fix an issue we are having on a number of machines I support and I need to modify the script to affect all user folders instead of the current user. Is there a succinct command or change I could make to reach all user folders?

```
@echo off
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
cls
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    @echo "Success Message"
    timeout 10
) ELSE (
    @echo "Error Message"
    exit 1001
)
```

For perspective the environment is a couple of physically separate computer labs on a shared domain where users log in via their domain accounts. The original issue was that the image that was deployed to all the machines ended up having the login cookie and webcache data for one of our IT users in the default profile that all of the other local profiles build off of. This image was deployed during christmas break so countless users have already logged onto (and created profiles) on various machines.

Comment: @rojo good call on the format edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go buddy.  Just loop through all directories of `c:\Users`, and `if exist (profiledir)` proceed with cleaning.  Use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) to handle success / fail (a little cleaner than `if %ERRORLEVEL%==0` I think), and `delayedexpansion` to evaluate variables within the loop.  If there's a non-zero exit on either side of the first `&&`, then the `||` code block fires.  In other words, the failed message occurs and error count increments if either `rd` or `del *` fails.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "errors=0"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:d c:\Users') do (

    set "DataDir=c:\Users\%%I\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    if exist "!DataDir!" (

        rd /s /q "!DataDir!" && (

            for /d %%x in ("!DataDir:\Local\=\Roaming\!\*") do (

                del /q /s /f "%%~fx\*sqlite" && (
                    echo account %%~nI: Cleaning of Firefox profiles succeeded.
                )
            )

        ) || (
            echo account %%~nI: Cleaning of Firefox profiles FAILED.
            set /a errors += 1
        )

    )

    endlocal
)

exit /b %errors%
```

Comment: Your script worked great and did what I asked it to do on all profiles unfortunately it seems the cause of the issue is something else, but than you very much for the quick response. Upvote and best answer.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15571285/1683264).  The cached auth info could be in `cookies.txt`, maybe.  I'll update my code to be a little more thorough.

Comment: its fixing the issue on profiles that have already been created, however when a new local profile is created the issue appears.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith Fixed I think.  **Edit:** Just fixed another bug.  Refresh.  Anyway, `for /d` doesn't include hidden directories.  `dir /b /a:d` does, though.  I switched the outer loop to use the `dir` command, so the hidden "Default" profile should now be included.  See if that works.

Comment: tested it and yeah seems to me working on all new profiles as well know after that further edit. Thank you again.